# Auto-reference .d.ts types from the same directory

Tags: typescript

I have a project where it is required to separate the TypeScript types from the actual TypeScript file on each module I write as shown below.

```
# folder structure

├── src 
  ├── foo.ts
  ├── foo.d.ts
```

---

```
// foo.ts
const Foo = (props: FooType) => { }
```

---

```
// foo.d.ts
export type FooType = {};
```

According to the official documentation, TypeScript compiler will infer type definitions for a module from a file that shares the same name as the module as long as it ends in `.d.ts`.

The problem I'm facing is that when I type my foo function in foo.ts, the TypeScript compiler complains `Cannot find name 'FooType'.ts(2304)`.

I know that I can manually import it from `foo.d.ts`. But is there any way (perhaps in tsconfig.json) to tell TypeScript Compiler to automatically import type definitions from `.d.ts` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself as I dug more into this particular problem...

According to the docs, TypeScript never searches for types in the same folder as the module is presented, as it errors on the cautious side thinking it could be `tsc` generated type definitions.